# AutoFixture.Xunit with Xunit.net 2.0 beta

Tags: nuget, xunit.net, autofixture

I've already moved to the xunit.net 2.0 beta version, but need some feature from AutoFixture, which still depends on the current 1.9.2 stable release (CompositeDataAttribute). As far as I see AutoFixture.Xunit hasn't been upgraded yet (when?)

When I just try to install AutoFixture.Xunit with nuget it complains of the conflict with it's dependency on xunit 1.9.2 and if I ignore dependencies it compiles but tests are not being run (at least by the VS2013 and Resharper runners)

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: A new (hypothetically called AutoFixture.xUnit.net2) glue-library *may* be released after xUnit.net 2.0 reaches a stable version.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis IIRC there is a branch somewhere - is that any use if one is prepared to get one's hands dirty -- or is that a bad idea?

Comment: I don't see any related branch: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/branches

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/294 (by @teadrivendev).

Comment: Thanks, tried it and also struggled with the issued mentioned in the pull request, I guess I'll wait for the official release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for xUnit.net 2 was [added to AutoFixture on April 8 2015](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/releases/tag/v3.25.0). It was added as a **new NuGet package**, in order to make it optional if and when to migrate to xUnit.net 2. Thus, there are two Glue Library packages for AutoFixture and xUnit.net:

- [AutoFixture.Xunit](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit) for use with xUnit.net 1.x
- [AutoFixture.Xunit2](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2) for use with xUnit.net 2.x